# ScheduledExecutorService which doesn't stop thread for uncaught exception

Tags: java, multithreading

From the docs here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

It says the following:

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent
>   executions are suppressed.

Is there any equivalent of ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate which doesn't shutdown after an uncaught exception?

Comment: Could you wrap your runnables in something which will catch the exception?

Comment: I second Andy Turner with the addition to log any caught exceptions. Don't swallow them silently even if you want to ignore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andy Turner mentioned, you could use a "Catch-All"-Wrapper:

```
public class CatchAllRunnable implements Runnable{
     private final Runnable wrappee;

     public CatchAllRunnable( Runnable r ){ wrappee = r; }

     @Override
     public void run(){
         try{ wrappee.run(); }
         catch( Exception e ){ /* LOG e */ }
     }
}
```

And then schedule :

```
yourScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( new CatchAllRunnable(originialRunnable), 1, TimeUnit.Minute);
```

The time of course adjusted to your requirements.